# Tableview multiple groups with different heights

Tags: iphone

I need to implement a  table view such that it has 3 different sections and each sections has 3 different height and different objects. i have set sections count to 3 but i couldn't find a suitable view to get the different heights.

How can i do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you mean, height of header for section? or cell?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello vishnu i am not a pro and i may be wrong. according to me if you want different height for defferent sections then for each section you have to give different cell height which inturn effect the height of section.

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    return 60.0f;

}
if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    return 100.0f;
}
else
    return 150.0f;
}
```

Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Did you use it

```
-rectForSection:  (and possibly also -rectForFooterInSection:)?
```

may this will help you ..